# Sum values from inputs and subtract from total

Tags: javascript, html

The point is that you can enter values in the fields, and the final result is obtained by subtracting from 100

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('injection-dist');
  var tot = document.getElementById('total').value;
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
      sum += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
  }
  final = tot - sum;
  document.getElementById('total').value = final;
}
```

```html
Qty1 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" class="injection-dist" name="qty[]" id="qty1" /><br> Qty2 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" class="injection-dist" name="qty[]" id="qty2" /><br> Qty3 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" class="injection-dist"
  name="qty[]" id="qty3" /><br> Qty4 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" class="injection-dist" name="qty[]" id="qty4" /><br>
<br><br> Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="100" />
```

The code works, but only when entering a single value. When entering a second value, some recalculation is done and the result is incorrect

For example, if we enter a value of 1 in a field, we get 99, but when we enter a subsequent value of 2 in another field, we get 96 instead of 97...

Thanks if anyone can help

Comment: If you add a `console.log(final, tot, sum)` after `final = tot - sum` you'll be able to see what's happening..

Comment: You keep adjusting the original total value. Unclear why you would subtract from the total to get a new total.

Answer (score 2):

I've removed the function that you had, since it was getting the value of **all** input fields at the same tame, and then basically doing `total - SumOfAllInputs` each time you change a value.

Instead, I created a list of all inputs, and added the `change` event for each of them, that gets the value **ONLY** of the one that is currently changed, and then do `total - thatValue`.

```js
var qty = document.querySelectorAll(".injection-dist"); //NodeList of all input fields

qty.forEach(function(item){ //iterate trough the list
item.addEventListener("change", function(){ // add change event for each of the elements (instead of onBlur)
var value = item.value; //get value of the inserted value
document.getElementById('total').value -= value;}); //change total value    
})
```

```html
Qty1 : <input  type="text" class="injection-dist" name="qty[]" id="qty1"/><br>
Qty2 : <input  type="text" class="injection-dist" name="qty[]" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty3 : <input  type="text" class="injection-dist" name="qty[]" id="qty3"/><br>
Qty4 : <input  type="text" class="injection-dist" name="qty[]" id="qty4"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="100" />
```